# How can I make the case statements show on 1 row? I get an error unless I put a group by, but then it groups by that and makes 2 different rows

Tags: sql

I have a query with multiple case statements but want them to show in 1 row and not group by the qualifier within each case statement.  Hours are marked in hours columns, but a bit to mark whether or not they are ST vs OT hours

I have tried putting a sum or max in front of the case statements, but then get an error.  "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery"

```
declare @StartDate as date
declare @EndDate as date
set @StartDate = '7/1/2019'
set @EndDate = '7/31/2019'

SELECT  js.City,
        ro.Name,    
        --sum(case when hw.overtime = 0 then SUM(hw.Hours) else 0 end) AS STHoursworked, 
        (case when hw.overtime = 0 then SUM(hw.Hours) else 0 end) AS STHoursworked, 
        --sum(case when hw.overtime = 1 then SUM(hw.Hours) else 0 end) AS OTHoursworked, 
        (case when hw.overtime = 1 then SUM(hw.Hours) else 0 end) AS OTHoursworked, 
        sum(hw.hours) as TotalHours
FROM            Manager.HoursInvoiced AS hw INNER JOIN
                         Manager.PayrollRecord AS pr ON hw.PayrollEntityOID = pr.EntityOID INNER JOIN
                         Manager.ClientAccounts AS ca ON pr.AccountEntityOID = ca.EntityOID INNER JOIN
                         Manager.Clients AS c ON ca.ClientEntityOID = c.EntityOID INNER JOIN
                         Manager.Assignments AS ass ON pr.AssignmentEntityOID = ass.EntityOID INNER JOIN
                         Manager.JobSites AS js ON ass.JobSiteEntityOID = js.EntityOID INNER JOIN
                         Manager.Role AS ro ON ass.RoleEntityOID = ro.EntityOID
WHERE        (c.EntityOID = 'D6F3BC50-B60E-4DA4-9F3E-DACE78FD0EE2') AND (hw.WorkDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
GROUP BY    hw.Overtime, 
            js.city,
            ro.Name 
order by js.City,ro.Name
```

[image]

[image]

I would like the STHours and OTHours for Conroe/Administrative to be on the same row.  I can't remove group by, and I can't use a max or sum function in front of case statements.

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Column 'Manager.HoursInvoiced.Overtime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: This is what you want: `sum(case when hw.overtime = 0 then hw.Hours else 0 end)`. The error was that you wanted to sum a summation, nested one aggregate inside another, but that's not necessary. Don't forget to remove that column from the `group by` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a `case` expression *inside* the summation. You want you lowest-level grouping to contain rows of both overtime and non-overtime type, you just want to selectively ignore them in the various totals.

The syntax error you received was the result of trying to sum a sum. (You might run across this in the setting of analytic functions but in this instance you can't do that here.)

```
select js.City, ro.Name,    
    sum(case when hw.overtime = 0 then hw.Hours else 0 end) AS STHoursworked, 
    sum(case when hw.overtime = 1 then hw.Hours else 0 end) AS OTHoursworked, 
    sum(hw.hours) as TotalHours
from ...
group by js.city, ro.Name 
order by js.City, ro.Name;
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  So obvious now, but just couldn't get what i was doing wrong!